# How to calculate average of list of qualifications of each pupil MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have this database and query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4cf72/116

And I would like to add a column with the average of the exam qualifications. However, I try doing this but it tells me there are more than 1 row on query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4cf72/115

```
    SELECT pupils.id_pupil, NAME, surname
       ,IFNULL(qua.media, 0)     media
       ,IFNULL(qua.count, 0)     number_class_qualifications
       ,(
         SELECT AVG(qualification)
           FROM   qualifications
                  JOIN pupils USING (id_pupil)
           WHERE  type_qualification     = 'exam'
                  AND id_trimester       = 1
                  AND LEVEL              = 1
                  AND class              = 'A'
           GROUP BY id_pupil
       ) AS exam_average,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_incident = 'miss' AND incidents.id_trimester = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS misses,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_incident = 'delay' AND incidents.id_trimester = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS delays,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_incident='attitude' AND incidents.id_trimester = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS attitude,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_incident='miss_justif' AND incidents.id_trimester=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS misses_justificadas
FROM   pupils
       LEFT JOIN incidents
            ON  incidents.id_pupil = pupils.id_pupil
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT id_pupil,
                       id_trimester,
                       COUNT(qualification) COUNT,
                       ROUND(AVG(qualifications.qualification), 2) media
                FROM   qualifications
                WHERE  type_qualification = 'class'
                GROUP BY
                       id_pupil,
                       id_trimester
            )                AS qua
            ON  (qua.id_pupil = pupils.id_pupil)
WHERE  LEVEL = 1
       AND class = 'A'
       AND qua.id_trimester = 1
GROUP BY pupils.id_pupil
```

The problem is on this sentence:

```
SELECT AVG(qualification)
FROM   qualifications
   JOIN pupils USING (id_pupil)
WHERE  type_qualification = 'exam'
       AND id_trimester   = 1
       AND LEVEL          = 1
       AND class          = 'A'
    GROUP BY id_pupil
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current subquery is returning the `avg(qualification)` for all `pupils` but it is not relating each row back to a single pupil.  You need to make this a correlated subquery which will query your `qualifications` while using the `pupils` from your outer query.  I would suggest rewriting the subquery query the following way:

```
(select avg(q.qualification) 
from qualifications q
where type_qualification='exam'
  and p.id_pupil = q.id_pupil
  and q.id_trimester=1 
group by q.id_pupil) as exam_average
```

You will notice that this subquery doesn't have the `JOIN` written inside of it but it is referencing your `pupils` table from the main ares of your query.  The full query would be written:

```
SELECT 
  p.id_pupil,
  p.name,
  p.surname,
  IFNULL(qua.media, 0) media,
  IFNULL(qua.count, 0) number_class_qualifications,
  (select avg(q.qualification) 
   from qualifications q
   where type_qualification='exam'
     and p.id_pupil = q.id_pupil
     and q.id_trimester=1 
   group by q.id_pupil) as exam_average,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='miss' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as misses,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='delay' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as delays,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='attitude' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as attitude,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='miss_justif' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as misses_justificadas 
FROM pupils p
LEFT JOIN incidents i
  ON i.id_pupil=p.id_pupil
LEFT JOIN
(
  select id_pupil, id_trimester, 
   count(qualification) count, 
     round(avg(qualifications.qualification),2) media
  from qualifications 
  where type_qualification='class'
  group by id_pupil, id_trimester 
) as qua
  ON qua.id_pupil = p.id_pupil
WHERE p.level=1
  and p.class='A' 
  and qua.id_trimester=1 
GROUP BY p.id_pupil, p.name, p.surname, qua.media, qua.count;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4cf72/120)

This could also be written without using the correlated subquery and you would JOIN on the subquery similar to:

```
SELECT 
  p.id_pupil,
  p.name,
  p.surname,
  IFNULL(qua.media, 0) media,
  IFNULL(qua.count, 0) number_class_qualifications,
  IFNULL(q.exam_average, 0) exam_average,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='miss' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as misses,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='delay' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as delays,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='attitude' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as attitude,
  sum(case when i.type_incident='miss_justif' and i.id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as misses_justificadas 
FROM pupils p
LEFT JOIN incidents i
  ON i.id_pupil=p.id_pupil
LEFT JOIN
(
  select id_pupil, id_trimester, 
   count(qualification) count, 
     round(avg(qualifications.qualification),2) media
  from qualifications 
  where type_qualification='class'
  group by id_pupil, id_trimester 
) as qua
  ON qua.id_pupil = p.id_pupil
LEFT JOIN
(
  select avg(q.qualification) as exam_average, q.id_pupil
  from qualifications q
  where q.type_qualification='exam'
    and q.id_trimester=1 
  group by q.id_pupil
) q
  on p.id_pupil = q.id_pupil
WHERE p.level=1
  and p.class='A' 
  and qua.id_trimester=1 
GROUP BY p.id_pupil, p.name, p.surname, qua.media, qua.count, q.exam_average;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4cf72/122). Both will generate the result:

```
| ID_PUPIL |         NAME |          SURNAME | MEDIA | NUMBER_CLASS_QUALIFICATIONS |   EXAM_AVERAGE | MISSES | DELAYS | ATTITUDE | MISSES_JUSTIFICADAS |
|----------|--------------|------------------|-------|-----------------------------|----------------|--------|--------|----------|---------------------|
|      140 |        María |     Adámez Nieto |     4 |                           2 | 4.733333269755 |      2 |      1 |        1 |                   2 |
|      141 |       Daniel | Alonso Fernández |     6 |                           3 | 8.400000095367 |      0 |      0 |        0 |                   0 |
|      142 |        Rocío |   Anos Población |     4 |                           1 | 6.366666634878 |      1 |      1 |        0 |                   1 |
|      143 |       Teresa |  Arribas Miranda |   3.5 |                           2 | 6.766666650772 |      0 |      0 |        0 |                   0 |
|      144 | Isabel María |    Barroso Suero |   5.5 |                           2 |              4 |      1 |      0 |        0 |                   1 |
```

Comment: Perfect! It works great! A lot of thanks!!!